# How fit my data to sinus?

Tags: plotting, fitting, data

I have problem with fit sinus to my date, because this sin is very tiny.
This is my code:

```
DANE = ReadList[
   "C:\\Users\\student\\Desktop\\jd100\\projekt\\wynik.txt", Real];
k = Length[DANE]/2;
xx = DANE[[1 ;; k]];
yy = DANE[[k + 1 ;; 2 k]];

dane2 = Transpose[{xx, yy}];


fit2 = FindFit[dane2, a0 + a1* Sin[a2* x + a3], {a0, a1, a2, a3}, x];

Show[{ListPlot[dane2 , PlotRange -> {{-500, 500}, {-500, 500}}], 
   Plot[fit, {x, -500, 500}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Automatyczne dopasowanie wielomianu", 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]}];
Show[{ListPlot[dane2 , PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-100, 100}}], 
  Plot[a0 + a1 Sin[a2 *x + a3] /. fit2, {x, -1000, 1000}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Automatyczne dopasowanie wielomianu", 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]}]
Show [ ListPlot[dane2 , PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-100, 100}}]]
```

And this is how this sinus looks like

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Please have a look at [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html?q=NonlinearModelFit).

Comment: Please provide your data!

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what i am starting learning mathematica and do you want from to change Fit to NonlinearFit?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FwPoxlQYpCFe9-Q-C83n-MIhlARai6qtdyt46xzFWUo/edit?usp=sharing it is that

Comment: @UlrichNeumann is it possible do it btw? Beacouse i am still trying and nothing :(

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data `dane2` is known:

With  `Method->"NMinimize"` NonlinearModelFit works fine

```
fit  = NonlinearModelFit[dane2,a0 + a1*Sin[a2*x + a3], {a0, a1, a2, a3},x,Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

modified axes ranges

```
Show[{ListPlot[dane2, PlotRange -> {{0, 5000}, {-60, 60}}], 
Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 5000}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLabel -> "Automatyczne dopasowanie wielomianu", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]}]
```

[image]

`Findfit` with modified Method works too:

```
fit1 = FindFit[dane2, a0 + a1*Sin[a2*x + a3], {a0, a1, a2, a3}, x, 
Method -> "NMinimize"] 
Plot[a0 + a1*Sin[a2*x + a3] /. fit1, {x, 0, 5000}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dane2 = Table[{x, 50 Sin[x/100] + RandomReal[{-4, 4}]}, {x, 0, 1000, 
20}];(*Generowanie danych -> dane2*)

fit2 = FindFit[dane2, a0 + a1*Sin[a2*x + a3], {a0, a1, a2, a3}, x, Method -> NMinimize]

Show[{ListPlot[dane2, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.015]], 
Plot[Evaluate[a0 + a1 Sin[a2*x + a3] /. fit2], {x, 0, 1000}, 
PlotStyle -> Black]}, 
PlotLabel -> "Automatyczne dopasowanie wielomianu", 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image]